# SQL Server using the REPLACE function to replace values in a column spanning multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table like this:

```
Rule    | Mask       |Replacement
---------------------------------
@ # 12  | @          |[^0-9]
@ # 12  | #          |[0-9]
```

That I constructed joining these two tables

Table 1

```
Mask_ID | Mask       |Replacement
---------------------------------
1       | @          |[^0-9]
2       | #          |[0-9]
```

Table 2

```
Rule_ID | Rule
--------------
1       | @ # 12
```

The result I want is this:

```
Rule    | Expression
--------------------
@ # 12  | [^0-9] [0-9] 12
```

I've been trying to use the REPLACE button to do this, but I've only been able to generate this result

```
Rule    | Expression
--------------------
@ # 12  | [^0-9] # 12
@ # 12  | @ [0-9] 12
```

I'm not sure how to get the REPLACE function to apply multiple rows to a single row. If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it.

This is what I have so far, but its causing me to get the result I mentioned above:

```
 SELECT 
  A.PointMask_CODE
  ,B.PointMasking_Rule_CODE
  ,B.Mask
  ,B.Escape_Character
  ,B.EscapedMaskRule
  ,REPLACE(A.PointMask_CODE, B.Mask, B.EscapedMaskRule)
 FROM
 tblStatusPointMasks_CORE A
 LEFT JOIN
 vwAORs_Status_PointMasks_EscapedRules B
 ON
 PointMask_CODE LIKE '%' + B.EscapedMask + '%' ESCAPE ISNULL(B.Escape_Character, '\')
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a relational design.  That is why you are having so much trouble with it.  You are effectively embedding arrays/lists of symbols in your Rule column and then trying to project it into a table-join.  Embedding arrays and lists into columns is a violation of First Normal Form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your given sample data, you could use a recursive [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

```
create table masks (mask_id int, mask varchar(32), replacement varchar(32));
insert into masks values
 (1, '@', '[^0-9]')
,(2, '#', '[0-9]');

create table rules (rule_id int, rule_txt varchar(32));
insert into rules values
 (1, '@ # 12');

with cte as (
  select 
      r.rule_id
    , r.rule_txt
    , masks = 0
  from rules r
  union all 
  select 
      r.rule_id  
    , rule_txt = convert(varchar(32),replace(r.rule_txt,m.mask,m.replacement))
    , masks = r.masks+1
  from masks m
    inner join cte r
      on r.rule_txt like '%'+m.mask+'%'
)
select top 1 * 
from cte
order by masks desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KAV58392

returns:

```
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| rule_id |    rule_txt     | masks |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
|       1 | [^0-9] [0-9] 12 |     2 |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option, using string operations...

```
create table masks (mask_id int, mask varchar(32), replacement varchar(32));
insert into masks values
 (1, '@', '[^0-9]')
,(2, '#', '[0-9]');

create table rules (rule_id int, rule_txt varchar(32));
insert into rules values
 (1, '@ # @ # 12');

declare @Table Table (charval varchar(10))
declare @char varchar(10), @rule_txt varchar(50)
select @rule_txt=rule_txt FROM rules
while charindex(' ',@rule_txt)>0
begin
    select @char=substring(@rule_txt,1,charindex(' ',@rule_txt)-1)
    FROM rules
    insert into @Table values (@char)
    SET @rule_txt=RIGHT(@rule_txt,(len(@rule_txt)-charindex(' ',@rule_txt)))
END
insert into @Table values (@rule_txt)
select stuff((SELECT ' '+isnull(replacement,charval)
 from @Table T left join masks M on M.mask=T.charval
  for xml path('')),1,1,'')
drop table rules
drop table masks
```